# How do I assign hyperlinks to drop down menus in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using the HYPERLINK function and finding it reliably useful. I'd value being able to assign hyperlinks (somehow) to individual menu drop downs.

Comment: not sure what menu dropdowns are. Do you mean a dropdown combobox?

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that you are talking about a drop-down via `Data Validation`.

As you cannot have both *formula* and *value* in the same Excel cell, you need to have another cell to build the hyperlink.

Let suppose you have your drop-down menu on column A.
You can put the formula in column B, something like:

```
=HYPERLINK([path]&A1,A1)
```